# starting tasks with lambda expressions in loops in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, lambda, task

In the preparation for a C# exam at university I found the following multiple choice question:

> Client applications call your library by passing a set of operations
>   to perform. Your library must ensure that system resources are most
>   effectively used. Jobs may be scheduled in any order, but your
>   librarymust log the position of each operation. You have declared this
>   code:
>
> ```
> public IEnumerable<Task> Execute(Action[] jobs)
> {
>   var tasks = new Task[jobs.Length];
>
>   for (var i = 0; i < jobs.Length; i++)
>   {
>       /* COMPLETION NEEDED */
>   }
>
>   return tasks;
> }
>
> public void RunJob(Action job, int index)
> {
>   // implementation omitted
> }
> ```
>
> Complete the method by inserting code in the for loop.  Choose the
>   correct answer.
>
> ```
> 1.)
> tasks[i] = new Task((idx) => RunJob(jobs[(int)idx], (int)idx), i);
> tasks[i].Start();
>
> 2.)
> tasks[i] = new Task(() => RunJob(jobs[i], i));
> tasks[i].Start();
>
> 3.)
> tasks[i] = Task.Run(() => RunJob(jobs[i], i));
> ```

I have opted for answer 3 since `Task.Run()` queues the specified work on the thread pool and returns a Task object that represents the work.

But the correct answer was 1, using the [Task(Action, Object)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Threading_Tasks_Task__ctor_System_Action_System_Object__System_Object_) constructor. The explanation says the following:

> In answer 1, the second argument to the constructor is passed as the
>   only argument to the Action delegate. The current value of the
>   i variable is captured when the value is boxed and passed to the Task
>   constructor.
>
> Answer 2 and 3 use a lambda expression that captures the i variable
>   from the enclosing method. The lambda expression will probably return
>   the final value of i, in this case 10, before the operating system
>   preempts the current thread and begins every task delegate created by
>   the loop. The exact value cannot be determined because the OS
>   schedules thread execution based on many factors external to your
>   program.

While I perfectly understand the explanation of answer 1, I don't get the point in the explanations for answer 2 and 3. Why would the lambda expression return the final value?

Comment: #1 is wrong - there's simply no reason for creating a cold task. The tutor wanted to demonstrate something different (lambda variable capture) and ended up with a very bad example

Comment: PS, did this question come from a certification example? Certifications typically use such trick questions because coming up with *good* questions is hard, especially for entry level certifications.

Comment: @SᴇM you're right. Starting tasks in a loop like that is seldom needed, which is why I didn't remember that `Run` doesn't take a state object. There's still no reason to create cold tasks

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos it could be from a certification example since the tutor is promoting certifications. I think you are right that the real purpose was to show lambda variable capture. In your opinion, would using Task.Factory.StartNew(Action<Object>, Object) be the right way to complete this sample?

Comment: Not unless you need the extra options it provides. [This article explains why](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html). You'd need to specify the [TaskCreationOption.DenyChildAttach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcreationoptions) at least.  You can create your own task factory with the options you want though. That's a lot better than using a cold task. With the cold task you'd have to remember to specify `DenyChildAttach` in every constructor call.

Comment: In answer 1, I don't get what type is "idx" in the beginning when generated by the lambda, and why does it have to be casted (and also, why would it be something that match with the jobs[] array ? Instead of some generic number?
Also, if there is a problem using i in the for loop, why do we systematically assign to task[i]? There would be the same problem, if i is 10 for all, then you will erase all but one task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In options 2 and 3 lambda captures original `i` variable used in `for` loop. It's not guaranteed when tasks will be run on thread pool. So possible behavior: `for` loop is finished, `i=10` and then tasks are started to execute. So all of them will use `i=10`.

Similar behavior you can see here:

```
void Do()
{
    var actions = new List<Action>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        actions.Add(() => Console.WriteLine(i));
    }

    //actions executed after loop is finished
    foreach(var a in actions)
    {
        a();
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
3
3
3
```

You can fix it like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    var local = i;
    actions.Add(() => Console.WriteLine(local));
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, you pointed me in the right direction. I now understand the point is in lambda variable capture.

Comment: I don't get why passing the variable to local will change the behavior, actually.
If it can be 10 when passed to Console.Writeline(i), it can be when passed to local. What am I missing? Thanks

Comment: @AndoJurai Without local variable the delegate uses the original `i` which is shared between all delegates. When you uses local variable the delegate uses concrete index.

Comment: thanks, but that's what I don't understand. What is the point of having i evolving if it doesn't affect what is in between the braces. Which it does, actually, since it changes local var. Why doesn't it do it for the delegate, is my problem, that makes no sense, since local IS current i, which is thus transmitted inside the loop. Why should it behave differently in the delegate expression? From a programming perspective, this is neither logic, nor understandable, nor clear, thus making application bug prone.

Comment: @AndoJurai I'm not sure that I understand your point. Two concepts are involved here: `deferred execution` of delegate and `variable capture`. Together they just work this way here and it's logical.

Comment: Normally, i changes of values are always reflected immediately within the scope of the for loop braces. Why doesn't it do it with a delegate, while a simple Console.Writeline(i) would be perfectly executed? Why is execution defered in the case of action.Add(), and why is a local variable passed by reference instead of by value (because I understand that being deferred, the C.W(local), having registered the reference to local, will only get it at last when executed). The problem is why?
That doesn't make sense that execution is deferred in the case of a loop...?
Thanks for your help

Comment: Delegate isn't executed until `a();` is called. About capturing variables in lambda expressions read here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions#capture-of-outer-variables-and-variable-scope-in-lambda-expressions